# Sort AndroidManifest File

Tags: android, xml, sorting, xslt

I am trying to sort a large android manifest file. Is there a standard way of doing this? I have looked into xslt but have yet to find a stylesheet that will do what I need.

A sample might be something like this, where I would want the output to be sorted by the name of the object recursively and then by android:name param on the object if it exists:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <permission />
    <permission-tree />
    <permission-group />
    <instrumentation />
    <uses-sdk />
    <uses-configuration />  
    <uses-feature />  
    <supports-screens />  
    <compatible-screens />  
    <supports-gl-texture />  

    <application>

        <activity>
            <intent-filter>
                <action />
                <category />
                <data />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data />
        </activity>

        <activity-alias>
            <intent-filter> . . . </intent-filter>
            <meta-data />
        </activity-alias>

        <service>
            <intent-filter> . . . </intent-filter>
            <meta-data/>
        </service>

        <receiver>
            <intent-filter> . . . </intent-filter>
            <meta-data />
        </receiver>

        <provider>
            <grant-uri-permission />
            <meta-data />
            <path-permission />
        </provider>

        <uses-library />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: "Is there a standard way of doing this?" -- parse it using your favorite scripting language, then generate your output according to your desired rules.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to do what you are saying. I can style the xml in IntelliJ but it doesnt rearrange the entries into alphabetical order and then by name. That is what I need help with.

Answer (score 0):

there is a way for doing this now, it won't exactly sort as you asked but it will at least order tags by their names. I have shown the method here.

1. Go to File | Settings | Editor | Code Style | XML | Arrangement(TAB)
2. add 2 rules at the top as shown in the image, Rules will be

**Rule 1**:

Type: Tag

Name: ^(?!application).*$

Order: Order By Name

**Rule 2**:

Type: Tag

Name: application

Order: Keep Order

[image: Matching rules]

**Note**: You can add more tags according to your needs.

**Note**: Make a 2nd Scheme for this code style to make sure it does not interfere with your other XMLs, after formatting Manifest always switch schemes.